LangChain Chroma, Retrieve not working with Trulens instrument
I have been trying to test my RAG application using TruLens. Whenever I try to use instrument by "from trulens.apps.custom import instrument", the retriever stops working.
Given below is the minimum code to reproduce the error.
from trulens.apps.custom import instrument
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain_huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain_community.docstore.document import Document

@instrument
def test_chroma_instrumentation():
    docs = [Document("This is sample text")]

    vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(documents=docs, embedding=HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name='sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2'))

    retriever = vectorstore.as_retriever()

    response = retriever.invoke("sample")

    print(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_chroma_instrumentation()


The code works as soon as I remove the decorator and import statement for instrument.
Expected the relevant documents to be retrieved and printed, but the code terminates on invoking the retriever.
Update: Ran the same code on Mac, works, when I tried to copy the libraries, only difference was it had Uvloop, a linux-based library.
